# Asymptotic expansion of an Integral depending on a parameter.

Tags: integration, asymptotics

Consider the following integral
$$I_n(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}(\cos \theta)^{x}(1+\sin 2\theta)^{4n+2}\cos((2(4n+2)-x)\theta)\,d\theta$$
for $x\in(-1,0)$. I am interested in showing that, for every $x\in(-1,0)$,  this integral is positive for large $n$.

Numerical experiments suggest that for $x\in(-1,0)$ the sequence
$((4n+2)^{1+x}I_n(x))_n$ converges and the limit $\ell(x)$ satisfies a simple inequality like $\ell(x)\ge -x/2$ which is enough to prove what I want.

I wonder if I can have some help to find the exact expression of $\ell(x)$ or if this is not possible to have a proof that $(4n+2)^{1+x}I_n(x)\ge -x/2$ for $n\ge n_0(x)$.